# Why doesn't the last if part work in onedit?

Tags: google-apps-script

Only the first if part is executed repeatedly and it does not go to the next if part.
I made a few dropboxes on different sheets. If you select one from the dropbox, another dropbox that matches the value is imported and pasted.
how should i solve it

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onEdit(e){

    if (sheet.getRange('C15').getValue() == 'line'){
    //Omit details
    spreadsheet.getRange('dropboxs!B2:C3').copyTo(spreadsheet. getRange('C18'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }

    if (sheet.getRange('C18').getValue() == 'c'){
    //Omit details
    spreadsheet.getRange('dropboxs!B2:C3').copyTo(spreadsheet. getRange('C21'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its unclear to me why you want this to execute every time you edit any cell.  I would also suggest you use the event object `e` rather than global variables.

Comment: Put `Logger.log(sheet.getRange('C18').getValue());` before last if statement